# How does the next object work in Linked List? How is it able to make another class objects point to the next address?

Tags: class, object, pointers, linked-list, iterator

```
class Node
{
    public int data;
    public Node next;
    
    public Node(int idata) {
        data = idata;
        next = null;
    }
}

Node newnode = new Node(val);
newnode.next = null;
```

Like if I'm creating a new object newnode of the class Node , how is it able to use .next to find the next address of the list?

Answer (score 0):

In your example code `next` is just `null`. Actually, it was not necessary to explicitly do `newnode.next = null;`, as it already was initialised to `null` in the `Node` constructor.

It becomes more interesting when you assign another new node to the `next` property of the node you have created:

```
Node newnode = new Node(1);
newnode.next = new Node(2);
```

In Java objects are accessed with references. `newnode` is such a reference, and `newnode.next` is also such a reference. Both are references to `Node` instances (if not `null`).

We could extend the linked list further:

```
newnode.next.next = new Node(3);
newnode.next.next.next = new Node(4);
```

When you realise that `next` is a property that can hold a value like any variable, then there is really no magic to it.

You could for instance also first create Node instances that are disconnected, and only after their creation link them together:

```
Node a = new Node(1);
Node b = new Node(2);
Node c = new Node(3);
Node d = new Node(4);

a.next = b;
b.next = c;
c.next = d;
```

Comment: I just have one more doubt, so like in your example if d is the last reference that we are adding will it automatically point to null? or we have to explicitly write d.next = null?

Comment: The `new Node()` call will execute the code in the constructor of the `Node` class, and there `next` is set to `null`. So no extra action is needed for the tail node.